# Find and Replace data source script

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, mxd

The following script is supposed to find and replace all shapefiles in a mxd (that exist in the folder) to the new SDE data source. No errors when running the script however, when I open the MXD in ArcGIS 10.1SP1 nothing changed.  Any suggestions what is wrong?

```
import arcpy, os, glob

#find all the MXD's in the directory tree
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\lmuhammad\Documents\ArcGIS\SearchandReplace\Testing"):
for filename in files:
    fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
    if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
        print "------------------------------"
        print filename
        #open the map document
        MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
        #get all the layers
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(MXD):
            #get the source from the layer
            if lyr.supports("datasource"):
                source = r"R:\Shapefiles\Road_Casings\RoadCasing.shp"
                print "%s -> %s" % (lyr, source)
                basename, extension = os.path.splitext(source)
                if extension.lower() == ".sde":
                    #This is the NEW SOURCE that you want to point to
                    datapath = r"Database Connections\Connection to GISD.sde\GISDEV.TRANSPORTATION\GISDEV.PAVEMENTEDGE"
                    #replace the old path wih the new
                    lyr.findAndReplaceDatasource(source, datapath, "NEWROAD", False)
        #save your changes
        MXD.saveACopy(r"C:\Users\lmuhammad\Documents\ArcGIS\SearchandReplace\Testing\test2.mxd")
        del MXD
```

Comment: It is obvious that the code is not going to do what you want as it is currently structured. Did you just copy and paste it from somewhere?

Comment: Yes I copied and paste it.. no one at ESRI Support or on GIS forums seem to know how to do a basic search and replace of datasources - from a shapefile to a sde_connection with multiple datasets & feature class for multiple mxds in a folder.

Comment: Where did you find the original script?

Comment: I found it here - http://www.sspinnovations.com/blog/2012/05/07/fixing-your-data-sources-python#comment-8

Comment: It works for feature classes that are in the same dataset..but not for different datasets.

Comment: Thanks for posting the original script. If you compare it to yours the problems should become apparent: http://diffchecker.com/5RK76F81

Comment: ...but not apparent to those that come a couple of years later @blah238 ;-) The link is broken, and even after making my own diff today with WinMerge I'm unsure which of the diffs made visible thusly are the "apparent" problem.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend breaking this up into two functions:

1. A function to replace the data sources in one MXD
2. A function that calls the previous function on each MXD in a directory tree

You'll want to test the first function thoroughly by itself before moving on to the second.

I recommend using a Python [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) such as [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) to develop, test and debug your scripts.

Please try to work at this yourself and if you run into a wall, edit your question to include the pertinent information such as what you tried (including **code!**), what you expected to happen, and what error messages or unexpected output you got.